# Sending post request with steambot

Tags: c#, http-post, steam, steambot

so i´m working on a program that sends a post request to a steamgroup, so that a announcement is created, but sadly it isn´t working well, i captured the "parameters" that are required with TamperData, and more or less tried to replicate it in c#.
Didn´t worked so well, maybe someone from here can help me.

```
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("sessionID", SteamWeb.SessionId);
        data.Add("action", "post");
        data.Add("headline", "EXAMPLE HEADLINE");
        data.Add("body", "EXAMPLE BODY");


        string url = "http://steamcommunity.com/groups/GROUP/announcements/create";
        string referer = "http://steamcommunity.com/groups/GROUP/announcements/create";

        SteamWeb.Fetch(url, "POST", data, false, referer);
```

Thats my code, maybe someone can help me.

regards

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: almost everything, no anouncement is posted.

Comment: Presumably you need to replace `GROUP` with your group's custom-URL...

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the posting with fiddler and it worked. Here are some hints:

1. The steam client is using the url `http://steamcommunity.com/groups/<GROUPNAME>/announcements` to post an announcement
2. You parameters are the right ones but the cookies are missing. You need two of them: The `sessionid` cookie contains the Session id (the same as in the parameter) and the `steamLogin` cookie (looks something like this:   `73561298352707625||62E520F5D92EFDE9C3794BFD00C739385B0AA77C`).

I have tested it Fiddler and it works.